# URL Redirection issue for hash(#)

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

I am sending mail using different file. My Main URL is something like this
`http://www.examplehasset.com/enquiry-form.php#quote_page`

from this page, i send enquiry. and after sending mail I wrote header loaction to redirect thank you page.

`header("Location: enquiry-thanks-you-page.php");
exit;`
so this line is working proper to redirect me on thank you page. but one issue is that character after (#) is also appended to my URL. so my thankyou page URL is looks like this.
`http://www.examplehasset.com/enquiry-thanks-you-page.php#quote_page`

I dont want `#quote_page` in URL. So let me know what is the method to do so? I just want the URL as follow. `http://www.examplehasset.com/enquiry-thanks-you-page.php`

Comment: Can u show the code you have written

Comment: Yes, show the page you have writen,  what you say you are doing does not have that effect when I do it.

Comment: @user3540050: You need to use Javascript to strip part after `#`

Answer (score 0):

Try to redirect with  # only **[ Work around ]** .(*See if it works across all browser*).

```
header("Location: enquiry-thanks-you-page.php#"); //See if it works
```